# Magento 2 Customer review report search Bug in all 2.1.x, 2.2

Tags: reports, magento2.1.5, magento2.1.6, magento-2.1.7, github

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Go to Reports -> By Customers
2. Enter customer name in search box
3. Click on search

It will show

> Fatal Error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_name' in
>   'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT detail.customer_id)
>   FROM review AS main_table

**I have found this bug in all Magento 2.1.x. And posted issue on github**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10301

Have anyone idea about this?

**EDIT:**

This issue still continues in **Magento 2.1.8, 2.2 and 2.2 EE**

Comment: Yes , alternative we have to use `firstname` instead of `customer_name`. Becuase `customer_name` not match with any table

Comment: You have any patch available for this issue?

Comment: Check my comment in below link, Its solved https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10301

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution...

**Create new module**

> Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Review"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Review\Customer" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Review\Customer" />
    <preference for="Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Customer\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Customer\Collection" />
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Review/Customer.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Review;

class Customer extends \Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Review\Customer
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $customerNameColumn = $this->getChildBlock('grid')
            ->getChildBlock('grid.columnSet')
            ->getChildBlock('customer_name');
        $customerNameColumn->setFilterIndex([
            'customer.firstname',
            'customer.lastname'
        ]);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Review/Customer/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Customer;

class Collection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Customer\Collection
{
    public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
    {
        if (is_array($field) && array_key_exists('like', $condition)) {
            $condition = array_fill(0, count($field), $condition);
        }

        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer :) +1 for you. Also if I not found any answer within 6 days I will give +50 boundary.  Yes I know we can override core file and solve this problem. But I don't need external module for it, I need patch for pull code on magento 2 github. If you found any patch for it. you can also pull code on magento 2 github repository.

Comment: you can create your own patch based on this module, but I don't like that way. you change core code.

Comment: Yes, you are right we should not change core but this is to help for Magento to implement this issue in next version. Anyway, I will try to create a patch for it.

Comment: @PrincePatel's idea is the way to go: provide a patch for this bug in order to let it get merged into the core -> you should try to get on GitHub and add one.